# springdata find top and composite key id

Tags: java, spring-data, dsl

Hi I'm trying to make a query to select my entity like this:

- get the entity with a restriction on one attribute of the composite ID
- and a restriction on the second attribute of the composite id (get the Top (max))

here is my Lot entity

```
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "idLot", column = @Column(name = "id_lot", nullable = false)),
@AttributeOverride(name = "versionLot", column = @Column(name = "version_lot", nullable = false, length = 10)) })
public LotId getId() {
        return this.id;
}
    ...
```

the composite ID

```
@Embeddable
public class LotId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idLot;
    private int versionLot;
...
```

and my query

```
public List<Lot> findTopById_VersionLotAndId_IdLot(@Param("identifiant") int idLot);
```

which gives me

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter available for part id SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1): [Is, Equals] NEVER.
```

Answer (score 1):

This did the tricks

```
Optional<Lot> findTopById_IdLotOrderById_VersionLotDesc(@Param("identifiant") int idIdLot);
```